# According to major Reformed theologians, what is the Christian fulfillment of the Songs of Ascent (Ps 120-134)?

Tags: exegesis, reformed-theology, psalms, typology, jerusalem

#### According to major Reformed theologians, what is the Christian fulfillment of the [Songs of Ascent](https://www.gotquestions.org/Songs-of-Ascent.html) (Ps 120-134)?

I'm particularly interested in **what a Reformed theologian determines to be the Christian referents of these 4 nouns** so that the verbs attached to them are meaningful in the Christian context in this age (today), **the verbs representing what a Christian can physically do**, just like how in the OT the Israelites would sing the Psalms as they physically ascended the mountain to go to the temple.

Secondly, the interpretation of these 4 nouns should be distinct (i.e. they cannot all be Jesus, at least they should be different aspects of Jesus).  For Catholics, the meaning can naturally be connected to ["going to mass"](https://media.ascensionpress.com/podcast/tjcs11/) to physically meet Jesus (the Eucharist) in the house of God (the cathedral) where the throne of the bishop (seat of authority for the bishop acting *in persona Christi*) is.  St. Peter's Basilica in the Vatican is on the [Vatican Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_Hill).

The 4 nouns are:

1. the physical city & walls of **Jerusalem**: "built as a city should be", "solidly united", "Feet were standing within"
2. the **physical temple** which is the house of God: "Let's go to"
3. **mount Zion** on which the city rests (or referring to the city): "where God desires it for his home", "those who trust in the LORD are like mount Zion", "the LORD bless you from Zion", "mountains surround Jerusalem"
4. the **thrones of the house of David**: "there thrones for judgment are placed"

Sample verses from the CSB translation:

- Ps 121:1: "I **lift my eyes toward the mountains**."
- Ps 122:1-2: "**Let's go** to the **house of the LORD**."  Our feet were standing **within your gates, Jerusalem**
- Ps 122:3-4: "Jerusalem, **built as a city should be**, solidly united, where the tribes, the LORD's tribes, **go up to give thanks** to the name of the Lord"
- Ps 122:5: "**There, thrones for judgment are placed**, thrones of the house of David."
- Ps 122:6-7: "Pray for the **well-being of Jerusalem**: "May those who love you be secure; may there be **peace within your walls**, security within your fortresses."
- Ps 125:1-2: "Those who trust in the LORD **are like Mount Zion**.  It cannot be shaken; it remains forever.  The **mountains surround Jerusalem and the LORD surrounds his people, both now and forever**."
- Ps 128:5-6: "May **the LORD bless you from Zion**, so that you will see the **prosperity of Jerusalem** all the days of your life ..."
- Ps 132:13-18: "For **the LORD has chosen Zion; he has desired it for his home**: "This is my resting place forever; I will make my home here because I have desired it.  I will abundantly bless its food; I will satisfy its needy with bread.  I will clothe its priests with salvation and its faithful people will shout for joy.  There I will make a horn grow for David; I have prepared a lamp for my anointed one.  I will clothe his enemies with shame, but the crown he wears will be glorious."

The answer should have references from Calvin's work, such as from his *Institutes of the Christian religion* or his commentaries on Scripture, **OR** from the work of a major historic Reformed theologian such as Jonathan Edwards, Charles Hodge, Abraham Kuyper, Herman Bavinck, etc.

Comment: I'm confused. The question relates to 'Catholics ... going to mass' but asks for 'Reformed Theologian' references. The Psalms of Degrees clearly depict an ascent which ends in 'Zion' (where is the Lamb and an innumerable company, forever). Thither the tribes go up - to new heavens and new earth - New Jerusalem _which is above_.

Comment: @NigelJ I am asking the Reformed theology's interpretation for the fulfillment of the 4 OT nouns.  As there are 4 nouns in the OT, the fulfillment needs also to be distinguished in 4 senses in the NT era.  I use the Catholic example to emphasize how in Catholic theology it's natural and easy to come up with 4 distinct fulfillment of each of the 4 OT nouns.  How about in Reformed theology?